# I think I broke gdm3 login by sudo pam-auth-update --force

Tags: pam

I was trying to solve a problem where the software updater would give me a message saying I was not permitted to use it, though I could do it from the terminal fine, and so I tried a remedy that suggested $ sudo pam-auth-update --force
Then I rebooted.  I ended at a black screen with an underscore cursor.   Now I cannot get a graphical login, though I can login remotely via ssh.  How can I fix this problem?  I'm using Ubuntu 22.10.

(I'm not 100% sure this caused my problem, but I think so.)

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this was to do a $ sudo pam-auth-update on another working ubuntu computer and duplicate all the settings that were enabled on it.  They were:

[ ] Pwquality password strength checking                                                                                           │
│    [ ] Fingerprint authentication                                                                                                     │
│    [*] Unix authentication                                                                                                            │
│    [*] SSS authentication                                                                                                             │
│    [*] Register user sessions in the systemd control group hierarchy                                                                  │
│    [ ] Create home directory on login                                                                                                 │
│    [*] GNOME Keyring Daemon - Login keyring management                                                                                │
│    [*] Inheritable Capabilities Management